# Javascript: global Var definition not at beginning

Tags: javascript, module, global-variables, closures, anonymous-function

I am trying to use a module pattern in javascript.

So far I have a file

global.js
which declares my global object
and I add a module container some other content which should be available in the global var MYAPP over all my modules I want to build.

```
var MYAPP = MYAPP || {};

MYAPP.modules = {};
MYAPP.segments = {
    seg1: "seg1",
    seg2: "seg2"
};
MYAPP.property = 1;
```

In another file I want to use an immediate function and pass my globals to it.

```
MYAPP.modules.m1 = (function (app, global) { 

    // Dependencies
    var segs = app.segments;

}(MYAPP, this));
```

After that I concatenate the files, but the globals.js file is not the first one, so the MYAPP declaration comes after the MYAPP.modules.m1 declaration.

So I get this when I run the code:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'modules' of undefined(anonymous function) @ module.js:1
```

I thought all the var declarations are moved at the beginning in javascript. Why is MYAPP undefined then?
Is it because an immediate function is called even before parsing the code after?
If so, how can I make it accessible for my module.js?

I tried to follow some stuff described here:
http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html

---

EDIT:
Alright I did not know that the var is only created and set to undefined.
I did not understand that concept that well. Thanks for that hint!

But still my question remains. How can I get my modules to work. Is putting my MYAPP declaration before the module declaration?
Or is there another solution?

---

EDIT 2:
In the meantime I realized that I would either have to manually check that the files are concatenated in the right order or that I would have to use a tool. Something like [require.js](http://requirejs.org) or maybe steal.js (?) or whatever. This would require to run the code on a node server (require at least). To use it in the browser I would probably need to browserify it.

Comment: Declarations aren't "moved", they are processed first and the variable assigned a value of *undefined*. The assignment using `=` occurs in sequence when execution reaches that place in the code. This misunderstanding is why the term "hoisting" is disliked.

Comment: Thank you. I did indeed not know that the vars are only assigned an _undefined_ value, but my question how to connect modules of my app remains (I also edited my question).